# SQLite statement working in database editor but not Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Maybe this is a simple problem, but I am just not seeing it :)

In my database, I have two fields named NoRide and NoAttempt.

In one row I have NoRide = 40 and NoAttempt = 40.

I have no issues when I query directly in the database using:

**SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NoRide = NoAttempt**

However in Android, I wrap this exact line in a rawQuery statement, and I get no results.  Similarly if I do things like

**rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NoRide - NoAttempt != '0'", null);**

I also get no data, when this query works fine in the database query.

Is there something different with rawQuery in android that I am missing?

Comment: i think its gives error when you try to print data using Cursor..

Comment: How so exactly?  I'm not getting any errors, just no values.

Comment: How are you determining that you get no results?

Comment: If I change the equation to say "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NoRide = '40'"  I am successfully pulling the cursor count as 1.  The same if I substitute NoAttempt = '40', so I know both have the proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's happening with the first part of your question (NoRide=NoAttempt), but I have an idea about the second issue.

Try removing the single quote from the 0... the database probably thinks you're trying to compare an int to a string. Lise so:

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NoRide - NoAttempt != 0", null);
```

Comment: Bingo, actually that did it, and I use that to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rawQuery("SELECT NoRide, NoAttempt FROM MyTable 
WHERE IFNULL(NoRide,0) - IFNULL(NoAttempt,0) <> 0", NULL);
```

Comment: No dice...same result (0 value).